# Prove spanning sets are equal

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $\vec{u},\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and S=span$\{\vec{u},\vec{v}\}$. Prove that $\{\vec{u}, \vec{v}-t\vec{u}\}$ also spans S for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

I was able to show that $\{\vec{u}, \vec{v}-t\vec{u}\}$ spans $\{\vec{u},\vec{v}\}$ by getting $\vec{x}=(m-nt)\vec{u}+n\vec{b}$ for $\vec{x} \in \{\vec{u}, \vec{v}-t\vec{u}\}$ and $m,n \in \mathbb{R}$.

I am stuck on how to show a linear combination such that $\{\vec{u},\vec{v}\}$ spans $\{\vec{u}, \vec{v}-t\vec{u}\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to show that $\text{span}\{u,v\} = \text{span}\{u,v-tu\}$

Let us prove the inclusion $(\subseteq)$ first.

If $w\in\text{span}\{u,v\}$, then we have that
\begin{align*}
w = w_{1}u + w_{2}v & = w_{1}u + w_{2}v + w_{2}tu - w_{2}tu\\\\
& = (w_{1} + w_{2}t)u + w_{2}v - w_{2}tu\\\\
& = (w_{1} + w_{2}t)u + w_{2}(v - tu)\\\\
& \Rightarrow w\in\text{span}\{u,v-tu\}.
\end{align*}

We may now approach the inclusion $(\supseteq)$.

If $w\in\text{span}\{u,v-tu\}$, then we have that
\begin{align*}
w & = w_{1}u + w_{2}(v - tu)\\\\
& = w_{1}u + w_{2}v - w_{2}tu\\\\
& = (w_{1} - w_{2}t)u + w_{2}v\\\\
& \Rightarrow w\in\text{span}\{u,v\}.
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 2):

We are given that every element $s \in S$ can be writen as $s = \alpha u + \beta v $ for scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Note that

$$  A u + B( v - tu )  = (A-t) u + B v $$

So, with $\alpha = A-t$ and $\beta = B$, we observe that $S = {\rm span} ( u, v-tu) $